# ¿Request a un webService encapsulado en un datagrama bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, rest, redes

Vereis, tengo un servidor en una raspberry. Este servidor genera una topologia de red distribuida basada en ad-hoc (Mesh Network). 
Tengo implementados varios servicios web (ver topologia, sniffer del tráfico en la red .. ).
La cosa es que ahora quería desarrollar una aplicación android que se sirviera de dichos servicios web.. Pero Android no permite conectarse a redes ad-hoc.. Por lo que no puedo acceder a esos servicios web.El servidor es LOCAL, por lo que obviamente si no estoy dentro de esa red no los puedo usar.
¿Como puedo hacer peticiones a esos servicios web?¿Se puede encapsular la peticion HTTP en un datagrama bluetooth y luego el servidor bluetooth de la raspberry procesar la petición y contestar al dispositivo android?
Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Si ambos dispositivos están en la misma red y tu raspberry está ejecutando un servidor web(apache, express,etc) entonces debes poder consumirlos utilizando la ip asignada a tu raspberry por tu router utilizando una página web y el navegador de tu dispositivo o con una aplicación móvil que utilice la ip asignada a tu raspberry.

Ahora si lo que quieres es exponer tus servicios web al mundo(que debes tomar en cuenta los riesgos que implica) puedes ocupar https://ngrok.com